# yii2 simple curl post returns 400

Tags: php, curl, yii2

Im simply trying to use curl to send some data to my other action. I know there are other ways to send data, but I need curl for future tasks.. So now Im just checking how it works... Anyway, I send data like this:

```
        $data = json_encode($model);
        //Init curl
        $curl = new Curl();

        //post http://example.com/
        $response = $curl->setOption(
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data)
            ->post('http://localhost/yii2/web/index.php?r=site%2Fdata');

        var_dump($curl->getInfo());die;
```

I am using the [linslin curl-extension](https://github.com/linslin/Yii2-Curl). But it does not work even with simple php curl.

The error is is that I am getting 400 error:

```
array (size=26)
  'url' => string 'http://localhost/yii2/web/index.php?r=site%2Fdata' (length=49)
  'content_type' => string 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' (length=24)
  'http_code' => int 400
  'header_size' => int 438
  'request_size' => int 218
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 0.125
  'namelookup_time' => float 0.016
  'connect_time' => float 0.016
  'pretransfer_time' => float 0.016
  'size_upload' => float 39
  'size_download' => float 15608
  'speed_download' => float 124864
  'speed_upload' => float 312
  'download_content_length' => float -1
  'upload_content_length' => float 39
  'starttransfer_time' => float 0.078
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
  'primary_ip' => string '::1' (length=3)
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'primary_port' => int 80
  'local_ip' => string '::1' (length=3)
  'local_port' => int 62464
```

What is wrong? Does it not like the `?r=site%2Fdata` part? If so, how to fix that ?

Comment: Do you think the URL path is correct (without the ? part)?

Comment: Do you send csrf token in your request ?

Comment: The URL works and yes I am sending the token'